# Grabing hashtagged word from a string using regex

Tags: c#, regex

Well, as the title says... I want to grab a certain word that is hashtagged in a string.

Example:
*This is a string that **#contains** a hashtag!*

I want to pick out the word **contains** from the string as a new string.

I can imagine that this is a very simple problem, but I really can't get it to work.

Comment: Please share what you've tried. It's usually quicker/easier to point out one error than cook up a solution from scratch. Or is the problem that you don't know where to begin?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How good do you want this pattern to be? In theory just:

```
"(?<=#)\w+"
```

would do it.

Edit, for more answer completeness:

```
string text = "This is a string that #contains a hashtag!";
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=#)\w+");
var matches = regex.Matches(text);

foreach(Match m in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you've missed escaping the backslash which I've now fixed.

Comment: You forgot the semicolons!

Answer (score 3):

```
string input = "this is a string that #contains a hashtag!";
var tags = Regex.Matches(input, @"#(\w+)").Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                .ToList();
```